# Is it possible to run a curl command with a splunk dbxquery?

Tags: rest, curl, splunk

I am developing a dashboard that connects to Splunk via REST API and displays data on various charts/graphs etc.  In order to get the data I have to make a POST request via curl (node.js).  Everything is working great.  However when I try to make a Post request with a dbxquery, it fails and returns 'fatal dbxquery unknown command.'  I was wondering if anyone had encountered this before.

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Basic auth token' -k https://devfg.com:8089/services/search/jobs  -d search=" | dbxquery query=\"SELECT count(*) FROM db.table\" connection=\"connection\"" -d output_mode=json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the permissions for the `dbxquery` command set to be executable from any app? Check under app permissions to see if the command is globally exported.

Alternatively, you may need to escape the `*`, so `\*`.

Otherwise, you should be able to run the `dbxquery` via a `curl` command.